# Incrementing a value through a URL passed parameter in PHP

Tags: mysql

Forgive my ignorance, but I am quite new to PHP/MySQL.

What I would like to achieve is, for a Top 10 on my radio station, I would like to allow the people to vote for individual songs, and when they do, increase the value of the number of votes in the database.

I pass the value of the song they clicked on through the URL: http://www.vlaamseradio.tk/top10/top10stem.php?Song=
It does display the song correctly on the page, saying "You voted for "Songname", but the votes value will not increase in the database.
Here is the code I used:

```
 <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="*****";
$pwd="****";
$port="";
$sys_dbname="******";
mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
$_GET[Song];
mysql_query("
    UPDATE Voting 
    SET Votes= Votes+ 1 
    WHERE Song = Song'
");
echo ("You voted for $_GET[Song]" );
?>
```

As I said: The message displays correctly, but the votes are not incremented.
Any idea where I am going wrong?
PS. I also tried to pass 2 values, such as http:/......./..php?Song=&id= but that will not work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query`. Also your `WHERE` part doesn't make sense (Song=Song will always return true).
Also consider using `PDO` or prepared statements in `MySQLi` to prevent `SQL` injection attacks.

Fixed code: (But please switch to PDO or prepared statements)

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="*****";
$pwd="****";
$port="";
$sys_dbname="******";
mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
$song = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Song']);
    $songSafeHtml = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Song']);
mysqli_query("
    UPDATE Voting 
    SET Votes= Votes+ 1 
    WHERE Song = '$song'
");
echo ("You voted for $songSafeHtml" );
?>
```

Fixed things above:
 - SQL injection (via mysql_real_escape_string)
 - XSS (via htmlspecialchars)

Comment: I'd +1 for recommending PDO, but using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `htmlspecialcharacters()` anyway to simplify your answer. Might want to comment why the latter. But also, while your correction is absolutely necessary here, I'm not sure this is the only problem. Would not `Song = Song` cause *all* rows to have their `Votes` incremented?

Comment: Nope, see my Song condition is Song = '$song', PHP will automatically embed the value of the $song variable. You can also add LIMIT 1 to be safe if you wish.

Comment: I was talking about the OPs code where `Song=Song`. The OP says the value is not being incremented, but the code the OP has in the question would cause *all* the rows to have their value incremented.

Comment: It's not incrementing because he's using mysql_query with a handle returned from mysqli_connect...

Comment: Oh!!! I see what you mean, now; OP used `mysqli_connect`, with the *i*, but then not the correspondingly correct `mysqli_query` I totally missed that - even though you explained it at the top! +1

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially about the security issue. I entered the code as you wrote it down, and it works, except for one thing: my votes are not incremented. I do get "You voted for......", but in the database, the vote count is still 0. Any further ideas, please. By the way, PDO is beyond me at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: I think I know why the value is not incrementing: it seems like the script is not connecting to the database (No idea why, though).

Comment: @user3592769 Having errors reported to you properly is absolutely vital for figuring out the issue. David has helped you here with other obvious errors there were in your code, but without specific error information, there's simple not enough information to help further.